# Loading Google charts without waiting google.charts.setOnLoadCallback() to retrieve all my document/page

Tags: javascript, charts

So my problem is a bit of a "long story" .
To make long story short, though, I am working on a dashboard and I am plotting a multitude of charts using flotCharts.

Lately, I needed another functionality for this dashboard that flotcharts could not provide, so I addressed to google charts. 
So now I am trying to use both flotchart google chart in the same page.

The way flotcharts are being populated is through a json object and each one of these plots is a different object, because I am using the same charts in the same page more than once.

```
function initiliseLineChart(identifier) {
     lineCharts[identifier] = new LineChart(identifier);
}
```

So function LineChart(identifier) creates and plots every flotchart that i am using.

Now I am trying to do the same thing with google time charts

```
function initiliseTimeChart(identifier) {
  google.charts.load("current", {packages:["timeline"]});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
        timeLineCharts[identifier] = new TimeChart(identifier);
    });
}
```

The problem is that i cannot access this TimeChart object while json is being retrieved, meaning i cannot populate the timechart, because the page is not fully loaded .

Any ideas how i can go around that, and not wait for the whole page to be fully loaded before I can play around with google charts ?